# Issue converting SQL column to CSV via XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I'm replacing a comma-delimited field in a SQL Server reporting application with a many-to-many relationship. The application code can't be replaced just yet, so I need to derive the same CSV column it currently expects. I've used the `FOR XML PATH` trick in the past, and it seems like a fast set-based solution that *should* easy to implement.

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT   
    Report = rr.Report_ID, 
    RoleList = STUFF((SELECT   ', ' + r.[Name] AS [text()] 
                      FROM [dbo].[Role] r 
                      WHERE r.Role_ID = rr.Role_ID
                      FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM     
    [dbo].ReportRole rr
ORDER BY 
    rr.Report_ID;
```

What I expect is this:

```
Report   RoleList
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  2      Senior Application Developer
  3      Senior Application Developer, Manager Information Systems
```

But what I get is this instead:

```
Report   RoleList
--------------------------------------
  2      Senior Application Developer
  3      Senior Application Developer
  3      Manager Information Systems
```

I'm using SQL Server 2017. Does this version not support the XML-to-CSV hack from previous versions?

Comment: It looks like you want to use `WHERE r.Report_ID = rr.Report_ID` instead of `WHERE r.Role_ID = rr.Role_ID`, but since you won't share the DDL, how can we know?

Comment: Original data is going to help us understand here. We can't see what you see.

Comment: The tables are normalized and the join table is a simple many-to-many ID map.  Role does not have a Report_ID, and Report does not have a Role_ID.


@Paurian's answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged your question with *SQL-Server 2017* and you ask:

> Does this version not support the XML-to-CSV hack from previous versions?

Yes, it does (as Paurian's answer told you), but it is even better: [This version supports `STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

Not knowing your tables I set up a *mini mockup* to simulate your issue (according to your *The tables are normalized and the join table is a simple many-to-many ID map*):

Two tables with a `m:n`-mapping table in between

```
DECLARE @mockupA TABLE(ID INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @mockupA VALUES(1,'A1'),(2,'A2');

DECLARE @mockupB TABLE(ID INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @mockupB VALUES(1,'B1'),(2,'B2');

DECLARE @mockupMapping TABLE(ID_A INT,ID_B INT);
INSERT INTO @mockupMapping VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(2,2);
```

--The query will simply join these tables, then use `GROUP BY` together with `STRING_AGG()`. The `WITHIN GROUP` clause allows you to determine the sort order of the concatenated string.

```
SELECT a.ID,a.SomeValue
      ,STRING_AGG(b.SomeValue,', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY b.ID) AS B_Values
FROM @mockupA a
INNER JOIN @mockupMapping m ON a.ID=m.ID_A
INNER JOIN @mockupB b ON b.ID=m.ID_B
GROUP BY a.ID,a.SomeValue;
```

The result

```
ID  SomeValue   B_Values
1   A1          B1, B2
2   A2          B2
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this.  It's a far simpler syntax, and feels less "hacky".  I used a CTE to join the aggregated columns to the non-aggregated, and it works like a champ.  From what I can tell, this is even better performing than the XML version.

Answer (score 0):

Having a table named "ReportRole" indicates a linking table between Report and Role in your case. If that's true, you could make the ReportRole table a part of your inner query and keep your Report IDs in the external query:

```
SELECT   
    Report = rpt.Report_ID, 
    RoleList = STUFF((SELECT   ', ' + r.[Name] AS [text()] 
                      FROM [dbo].[Role] r
                           JOIN [dbo].ReportRole rr
                             ON r.Role_ID = rr.Role_ID
                      WHERE rr.Report_ID = rpt.Report_ID
                      FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM     
    [dbo].Report rpt
ORDER BY 
    rpt.Report_ID;
```